# Compute variable only for cells with no missing values [SPSS]

Tags: syntax, spss

I have three variables: height, weight, and obesity
Both height and weight are continuous variables, while obesity is a categorical variables

Entries for obesity are=

- 1 = Obese
- 0 = Not obese
- 999 = Unknown
- $SYSMIS = Missing values

I would like to convert cells with 999 and $SYSMIS to 1 or 0 according to their BMI (>=25 for obese).

Here is my current code:

```
IF (MISSING(OBESITY) & NOT(MISSING(HEIGHT) | (HEIGHT = 0)) & ((WEIGHT / (HEIGHT * HEIGHT)) >=25)) OBESITY.1=1.
IF (MISSING(OBESITY) & NOT(MISSING(HEIGHT) | (HEIGHT = 0)) & ((WEIGHT / (HEIGHT * HEIGHT)) <25)) OBESITY.1=0.
IF ((OBESITY=999) & NOT(MISSING(HEIGHT) | (HEIGHT = 0)) & ((WEIGHT / (HEIGHT * HEIGHT)) >=25)) OBESITY.1=1.
IF ((OBESITY=999) & NOT(MISSING(HEIGHT) | (HEIGHT = 0)) & ((WEIGHT / (HEIGHT * HEIGHT)) <25)) OBESITY.1=0.
EXECUTE.
```

However, running this code returns error:

```
 >Warning # 511 
    >A division by zero has been attempted on the indicated command.  The result 
    >has been set to the system-missing value. 
    >Command line: 315  Current case: 655  Current splitfile group: 1
```

And the computation returns erroneous ($SYSMIS for all cells). I am not using any split file or select cases feature

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Probably including the calculation of the BMI as part of the `IF` conditions forces the calculation even when there are missing values or zeros in the `height` variable.
The following code is more efficient and will hopefully also solve your problem:

```
if (MISSING(OBESITY) or OBESITY=999) and not(MISSING(HEIGHT) or HEIGHT = 0)
      OBESITY.1 = (WEIGHT / (HEIGHT * HEIGHT))>=25 .
```